# How to use Selling Feature in Facebook groups using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently Facebook introduced Selling feature in Facebook groups but I guess the Graph API is missing to use this feature. If this is available please tell how to use.

Relevant images are attached here.

**This is the graph api request for the feed of the group :**
[image: This is the graph api request for the feed of the group.]

In this image you can see that products are differently classified. Like their price, contact details.
[image: This is over all feed of the group]

**This is how a user can manually post on facebook:**
[image: Posting option in Selling Groups]

**And this is the *only products feed*** : 
[image]

**EDIT :** 
Here is information of one post retrieved using graph api and request mentioned in first pic

```
{
 "data": [
{
  "id": "230059773786620_695552487237344",
  "from": {
    "id": "809217099193795",
    "name": "Sukanta Roga"
  },
  "to": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Buy n sell @NIT silchar",
        "id": "230059773786620"
      }
    ]
  },
  "message": "200 NS for sell
₹75,000 - Contact no. 09436157708

The condition of the vehicle is very good. It has runs 11000 Kms. The  price tag is negotiable. All the documents regarding registration are clear. Please contact PG hostel for more details.",
  "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/10250295_802608569854648_5409368019938464401_n.jpg?oh=be63633e7a684e65c64d6cc13b513456&oe=562C9779",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=802608569854648&set=gm.695552487237344&type=1",
  "icon": "https://www.facebook.com/images/icons/photo.gif",
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/230059773786620/posts/695552487237344"
    },
    {
      "name": "Like",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/230059773786620/posts/695552487237344"
    },
    {
      "name": "Share",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/230059773786620/posts/695552487237344"
    },
    {
      "name": "Create Group Chat",
      "link": "/groups/230059773786620/"
    }
  ],
  "privacy": {
    "value": "",
    "description": "",
    "friends": "",
    "allow": "",
    "deny": ""
  },
  "type": "photo",
  "status_type": "added_photos",
  "object_id": "802608569854648",
  "created_time": "2015-06-22T07:15:14+0000",
  "updated_time": "2015-06-22T07:15:14+0000",
  "is_hidden": false,
  "is_expired": false,
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "856694037754846",
        "name": "Roshan Prasad"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "after": "ODU2Njk0MDM3NzU0ODQ2",
        "before": "ODU2Njk0MDM3NzU0ODQ2"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question – whether you can _create_ those type of posts via API? If so, the answer is no, that is currently not possible.

Comment: Ok. And how can I use API to retrieve those posts? I mean with those fields (price, pick up options, etc ) too.

Comment: @HarshVardhanLadha Have you get any solution for it ? I am still looking how to post Price and Location .. so It look in better way at Facebook

Comment: @Dhiraj no.. I am just posting it as news feed gets posted.
There is no API implementation for it and I don't think that FB.DEV will provide it because `publish_actions` should be performed on user written content you cannot modify it at all otherwise you will not get your FB.APP approved!

Comment: Any update to the ability?  I have some potential clients that could use a way to centrally manage their inventory but post to CraigsList, Facebook, & their site, from a single IMS screen.

Comment: Until and unless facebook dev doesn't provides this API, it cannot be processed. and I guess this API is privately used.

Comment: How did you took a graph response, from EDIT?

Comment: @DmitryPolushkin I have used Graph API Explorer to make the request, the first image can describe clearly at what edge you need to make the request.

Comment: @HarshVardhanLadha haven't noticed it's from the first picture. Seems there are no solution at the moment to receive only the products feed.